# bash: /bin/ping: Operation not permitted on rhel 7.1 docker image

Tags: docker, ping

```
[root@e732ba272c77 chef-repo]# ping www.google.com
bash: /bin/ping: Operation not permitted
```

tried giving execute permission on /bin/ping   but not working

Comment: what's the image name?

Comment: RHEL 7.1 official image

Answer (score 4):

```
[root@e732ba272c77 chef-repo]# setcap cap_net_raw+ep /bin/ping 


[root@e732ba272c77 chef-repo]# ping www.google.com            
    PING www.google.com (173.194.121.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=69.1 ms
    64 bytes from iad23s26-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.121.50): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=68.7 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

you should start the docker container with CAP_NET_ADMIN privileges as the ping command needs this.

```
docker run --cap-add net_raw --cap-add net_admin <other options> <container name>
```

You can refer to this link for more information on this: [How to enable ping in RHEL 7.1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unable-to-use-ping-in-centos-linux-rhel-7-docker-container/)